# Dockerfile behaving differently on different machines

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running into a seemingly impossible situation: I am building a .Net application with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS netbuild
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=netbuild /app/MyProject/out .

#Some other things and an entrypoint
```

And my build command is

```
docker build -t myapp:test -f Dockerfile-backend-only .
```

On my local machine this works perfectly fine. However, when I run it on a different machine, which serves as a build agent, dotnet publish decides to put the result of the build into *C:\app\out* instead of *C:\app\MyProject\out*.

Now I already read that the behaviour of the *-o* option for relative paths changed in some releases of the build tools, but this is a Dockerfile, so this shouldn't have any effect. Also both machines are running Win 10 Pro and have up-to-date Docker installations.

Comment: try to docker pull, maybe there is an old image in ine of the machines

Comment: That was it, thanks.